# How do I enable query string in Cloudflare page rules?

Tags: cloudflare

I want to forward this URL

`https://demo.example.com/page1?v=105`

to

`https://www.example.com/page1`

It's not working if I set so:

[image]

But if I remove the `?v=` part, it works:

[image]

Is there any way to include the `?v=` part in this page rule?

Answer (score 0):

The rule you mentioned works only for that exact URL: `https://demo.example.com/page1?v=105`. If it has any additional query parameter or even an additional character, eg `https://demo.example.com/page1?v=1050`, it won't match the rule.

If you need to use complicated URL matches that require specific query strings, you might need to use bulk redirects or a Cloudflare worker.